# Unable to obtain header values with FastAPI middleware

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fastapi

I have limited knowledge of FastAPI.
Thanks for any help you can give me.

I want to get a token and process it in the middleware.

However, the problem occurs at the link.

https://github.com/fujitomo/menta-todo/blob/fuji/FE-0004_login/backend/src/other/middleware.py#L30

I have a value set in the header access_token.
However, the header value is set as follows

`'access-control-request-headers': 'access-token,content-type',.`

The access-token value is set to None.

However, if the following link is set to `if True:`, the value is set without any problem.

https://github.com/fujitomo/menta-todo/blob/fuji/FE-0004_login/backend/src/other/middleware.py#L30

Do you know the cause of this problem?

I tried Authorize with the following link and the result was the same.

https://indominusbyte.github.io/fastapi-jwt-auth/usage/basic/

Requesting from the Swagger UI, the token value can be obtained without problems.

The problem is when a request is made from React using the process linked below.

https://github.com/fujitomo/menta-todo/blob/fuji/FE-0004_login/backend/src/other/middleware.py#L30

Comment: The header you're showing seems to be from the OPTION request, where the header isn't set - the client is saying _which_ headers it might include in the request, not that the headers are set. Usually you'd use the `Authorization` header to include a JWT, such as `Authorization: Bearer <JWT>`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I had the same symptoms even though I had set it up in Authorize.
However, when I modified it again, I was able to retrieve the value.
If I can confirm the cause, I will record it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much Python i can soy maybe the problem comes from using underscore (_) or dash (-) when declaring and using access_token and access-token.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
It seems that modifying access_token to aceesstoken gives the same result.